# Outlook 2010 Search in all mailboxes

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, search, mailbox, shared-mailbox

At a new workplace I'm working with Office 2010 (sadly :/) I ran into one of those unsolvable user problems. So here is the issue.

A user with 2 shared mailboxes wants to look in all 3 mailboxes he has. When I am inside Mailbox A I can find all the mails in the inbox and subfolder. Which is fine. From Mailbox B I try to look with the setting "All Mail Items" and also "All Outlook Items" but apparently it won't show the mails I find when I am inside of Mailbox A.

So the issue is that I cannot search any mails when I am not directly inside the Mailbox which contains those mails. For the settings, the cached exchange mode is disables by default so the option "download shared folders" is also unchecked and also greyed out.

Please help me with this issue as it's driving me mad. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search scope are limited depends on the configuration. We are limited to using the "Current Folder" search scope when searching in a shared mailbox if the shared mailbox is added via the Exchange email account’s Advanced tab (using the Open these additional mailboxes option) or via Auto-Mapping.

If we want to search entire mailbox, we can add the shared mailbox as a second Exchange account. The Subfolders and Current Mailbox scopes also require FullAccess permission to the shared mailbox.

[image]

You can check this thread: [Shared Mailbox Search Functionality](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/182d5424-3af3-4043-9d19-d0938fb8629a/shared-mailbox-search-functionality?forum=outlook)

Comment: Thank you very much. If only I had found this myself when looking it would have safed me a lot of time. Even if office 2010 should be extinct some companies probably keep using it for moneysaving reasons. I do hope that this then also helps others looking for this issue. I can now check with my colleages if we want to make some changes.
Afaik the users are added as mailbox delegation via the Exchange admin center. Once in "Send of Behalf" and also under "Full Access". So they don't fall under the last 2 points.
Thx for the link and the table. Very appreciated here. :)